# Verb + ed for Present Tense

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense, past-simple

Is the sentence below in present tense or past tense?

> I just entered my house.

If we give context to the above sentence, can we fit this in both the tenses?

> a) I just entered my house to see xyz. (Present tense)
>
> b) I just entered my house and saw he was killing xyz. (Past Tense)

When we use verb+ed it suggests past tense. But in following examples verb+ed is also used for present tense.

> c) I just finished my race.
>
> d) Yes, now I made it.

Answer (score 1):

> **I just entered my house to see xyz**

It is also past tense.It talks about the recent past.

> **I just finished it**

The above sentence is in the past.If we use Just, it does not mean that it is present.It refers to recent past.

> **I have just entered my house**.

It is called the present perfect which talks about the recent past but completed action.

**I have passed my M.A exam**

It is also called present perfect but the action might have happened long ago.

> **Now I made it**.

**Now I made it** is a song.In songs we can not search for grammatical correctness.

It is also past tense though it refers to present time.

In English there is no one to one correspondence between time and tense.